# Is there any point in getting Block Damage Resistance on The Conqueror?

Tags: for-honor

From what I've found on the internet so far Block Damage Resistance seems to lower the damage you recieve from blocked heavy attacks.

I know that most classes recieve some damage on merely blocking (not parrying) a heavy attack since they don't have superior block. 
The Conqueror however has superior block on all his normal blocks which means he completely ignores heavy attack damage if he manages to block it.

Now I know that there is the Full Block Stance that doesn't have superior block properties, but is this really the only situation where this stat *might* be useful? Or am I missing something here?